# C++ abstract type declaration

Tags: c++, itk

I am using ITK. `itk::LinearInterpolateImageFunction` is a subclass of `itk::InterpolateImageFunction`.

Why is the statment below not valid?

```
itk::InterpolateImageFunction<ImageType,double>::Pointer interpolator = itk::LinearInterpolateImageFunction<ImageType, double>::New();
```

The error I get is

> error: conversion from
>   `itk::LinearInterpolateImageFunction<itk::Image<unsigned char, 3u>,
>   double>::Pointer {aka
>   itk::SmartPointer<itk::LinearInterpolateImageFunction<itk::Image<unsigned
>   char, 3u>, double> >}` to non-scalar type
>   `itk::InterpolateImageFunction<itk::Image<unsigned char, 3u>,
>   double>::Pointer {aka
>   itk::SmartPointer<itk::InterpolateImageFunction<itk::Image<unsigned
>   char, 3u>, double> >}` requested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `InterpolateImageFunction::Pointer` typedef is to `SmartPointer<InterpolateImageFunction>`.  Unlike `std::shared_ptr`, `itk::SmartPointer` does not support conversions between smart pointers of related types.  That is, `InterpolateImageFunction<X,Y>::Pointer` and `LinearInterpolateImageFunction<X,Y>::Pointer` are unrelated types.